# Am I calling these functions correctly?

Tags: c++

Please tell me if there is any error when I am calling these functions

**1 bool discount (float price, int numberOfItemsPurchased)**

```
bool discount
float price;
int numberOfItemPurchased;

discount = discountP (price, numberOfItemPurchased)
```

**2 float estimatePetrolPrice (float kms, float price, bool leaded, bool automatic)**

```
float estimatePrice;
float kms;
float price;
bool leaded;
bool automatic;

estimatePrice = estimatePetrolPrice (kms, price, leaded, automatic)
```

**3 void getData (string & name, string & dateOfBirth, int & age)**

```
string name;
string dateOfBirth;
int age;

getData (name, dateOfBirth, age)
```

**4 void getVal ( int & item, int & inter, char decflag)**

```
int item;
int inter;
char decflag;

getVal (item, inter, decflag)
```

Comment: Sorry, is this a programming problem? What's your code?

Comment: What's the actual *problem* here?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's right. You pass arguments declared with the same type as in the function's declaration, and assign the return value to a variable of the right type if it isn't void.